# itext flat field increase file size

Tags: itext

I have found that after commit bd5c1fdee48184fa97c4b12afb4370712acf1263 if I run this code using this [sample pdf](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9OKk0hk4OhzMkJ0VERIMUhQdkk) I get a 12MB file.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("/tmp/tpl2.pdf");
AcroFields fields = r.getAcroFields();
if(fields != null && fields.getFields() != null && fields.getFields().size() > 0) {
    OutputStream out = null;
    out = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/testDim.pdf");
    PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(r, out);
    stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
    AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields();

    Set<Entry<String,Item>> map = form.getFields().entrySet();
    for (Entry<String, Item> e : map) {
        form.setField(e.getKey(), e.getKey());
    }

    stamp.close();
    out.close();
}
r.close();
```

If I do the following patch on 5.5.10, I get 144kB file.

```
diff --git a/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamperImp.java b/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamperImp.java
index 2309003..dc58a63 100644
--- a/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamperImp.java
+++ b/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamperImp.java
@@ -929,7 +929,9 @@
                 PdfDictionary appDic = merged.getAsDict(PdfName.AP);
                 PdfObject as_n = null;
                 if (appDic != null) {
-                    as_n = appDic.getAsStream(PdfName.N);
+                    as_n = appDic.getDirectObject(PdfName.N);
+                    if (as_n == null)
+                        as_n = appDic.getAsStream(PdfName.N);
                     if (as_n == null)
                         as_n = appDic.getAsDict(PdfName.N);
                 }
```

I do the patch because I try to revert the only relavant part of the commit, but I don't know if it is safe, do you think that it can be.

Thanks

Comment: Please make a pull request on the GitHub repository: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/pulls.

Comment: The example file is broken. Did you already experiment with the broken file or did it break when you shared it here?

Comment: Hi, I just download the file a it seems OK, can you explain me why you say that the file is broken? Thanks.

Comment: I do the PR on [github](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/pull/28).

Comment: *"can you explain me why you say that the file is broken"* - unfortunately I seem to not have had been informed by SO about your comment, Alexey's edit brought your question up again. You probably should have used "@mkl" to make SO signal me. I don't know anymore what exactly I saw two and a half months ago. A quick check shows some issues, Adobe Preflight complains about missing **SubType** entries in numerous XObjects, and the second document line looks like there might once have been a problem caused by some software applying string encoding, but I cannot find really bad issues.

Comment: @mkl I'm sorry, the file is the wrong one, trye [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9OKk0hk4OhzZjZuLUVhakc0TDg).

Comment: Yes, it is plausible that for your document it makes a big difference how forms are flattened. (And itext should be optimised to treat this sensibly.) But as such a document is very uncommon (so many form fields with so few shared appearances), that might not be top priority.

Comment: @mkl the document is a test document, in my real case I have a 80 pages document with many fields, some of them are with same name repeated in each page. With this document the difference is from 700kb to 5Mb.

Comment: Ok. Well, you showed where to optimise after all...